# How to send Http response to specific requestLine in python?

Tags: python, http, request, response

Can I send a http response to a specific requestLine outside the function I received the request in it.
As an example I receive the request then pass this request to some functions and I want to send a response to this request, if there is allowed?

Comment: Provide details. Share your research or your code. see (https://stackoverflow.com/help)[help] and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to split the path your program is taking, so it's doing two different things at the same time, then you'll need to utilize control-flow constructs that do this like threads/processes/events/async.

You might want to look at Celery (http://www.celeryproject.org/) and Jobtastic (http://policystat.github.io/jobtastic/).